Unable to install Windows 10 with Boot Camp
I am unable to install Windows 10 with Boot Camp, as when I reboot into the Windows partition to continue with the installation, I face the following error:
Windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattend answer file’s <ImageInstall> setting. Make sure the setting references a valid partition and restart the installation.
I have seen answers online that suggest removing a portion of the file AutoUnattend.xml at the root of the OSXRESERVED partition. However, as I've also found out online, newer macs/macOS versions have forgone the need for this file, with it being generated on-the-fly during installation.
I have tried to manually install Windows without Boot Camp, with the use of a bootable USB. However, I'm faced with the following error after pressing the Install button:
Windows Setup could not install one or more boot-critical drivers. To install Windows, make sure that the drivers are valid, and restart the installation.
I have also attempted to manually create an OSXRESERVED partition - by wiping it, then copying over the contents of the bootable USB into the partition. This time, after I press the Install button, the following message appears:
No device drivers were found. Make sure the installation media contains the correct drivers and then click OK.
Then, when I click the 'Browse' button to look for drivers, the only folder I can access is the Boot partition under X:, which has a completely different directory structure as compared to the OSXRESERVED partition as seen on macOS.
In all three cases, I have verified that both the $winPEDriver$ and BootCamp folders exist at the root of the installation partition, and I have verified that the necessary drivers, including AppleSSD drivers, are present in those folders.
The following is my partitions list, from diskutil list:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk0
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         2.0 TB     disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s1
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     971.2 GB   disk1s2
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 2.1 GB     disk1s3
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                1.2 GB     disk1s4
   4:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            10.2 GB    disk1s6
   5:              APFS Snapshot com.apple.os.update-... 10.2 GB    disk1s6s1
   6:                APFS Volume VM                      20.5 KB    disk1s7

I have previously installed Windows on this machine without issues, but due to insufficient storage on it, I wiped it, and now I am attempting to reinstall it.
I suspect it's a missing EFI partition before Container disk1.
How can I fix this, and properly install Windows? Preferably I do not want to wipe my entire machine and reinstall macOS, as I have about 1TB of data for work that I do not want to lose, and I also do not have a 1TB drive to backup my data to. Where I live, these drives are expensive, and I do not have a method to obtain one to backup my data.

Post the output from the command diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Offset -e Size. This will determine how must free space resides where the EFI partition would normally appear in a macOS installation. It also might be useful to know the version of macOS and the model/year of your Mac.
